# Geometric example of quasi-abelian category (not abelian)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, applications

Good morning to everyone,

I am writing here because I need to understand better some topics about quasi-abelian homological algebra.

Is there an example of quasi-abelian category and non abelian, in geometrical topics? I mean strictly speaking, algebraic geometry, sheaves, number theory .....

I did not study advanced topics about these subjects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wikipedia contains several examples, but you may want to check them yourself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think the standard example in algebraic geometry (that I know of) is the category of torsion free sheaves on a smooth projective variety $X$.

This also comes up in Bridgeland's paper *Stability Conditions on Triangulated Categories* where the notion is used to prove his deformation theorem which says that the space of stability conditions (under suitable hypotheses) of a triangulated category $\mathcal{D}$ is a complex manifold.